# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have an social media app that stores data about a video in FirebaseDatabase (version: `19.4.0'`). The actual class is below.

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class RemoteUserVideo(val url: String, val description: String?, val tags: List<String>, val duration: Long, val key: String, val dateCreated: Long, var likes: Long = 0, var views: Long = 0, val creatorUid: String,  var totalCommentsSize: Long = 0, var videoThumbnail: Bitmap? = null): Parcelable {
    constructor(): this("", null, listOf(), -1, "", -1, -1, -1, "",  -1, null)
}
```

```kotlin
//      This is the actual list of Strings
        val descriptionText = "Soar like an eagle. #vision #dream #soarHigh"
        val stringArray = descriptionText?.split(" ") ?: listOf()
        val dummyTags = ArrayList<String>()

        stringArray.forEach {
            if (it.startsWith("#")){
                dummyTags.add(it)
            }
        }

        Timber.d("dummyTags as List is ${dummyTags is List<*>} and dummyTags as Array is ${dummyTags is Array<*>}")

//      The above logs returns 'dummyTags as List is true and dummyTags as Array is false' 

        val globalVideosRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(getAllVideosPath()).push()
        val databaseRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("${getUserPublicVideosPath()}/${globalVideosRef.key}")

        val remoteUserVideo = RemoteUserVideo(
            url = videoUrl,
            description = descriptionText,
            tags = dummyTags.toList(),
            duration = localUserVideo.duration?.toLong() ?: return,
            key = globalVideosRef.key.toString(),
            dateCreated = System.currentTimeMillis(),
            likes = 0,
            views = 0,
            creatorUid = firebaseAuth.uid ?: return,
            videoThumbnail = bmp
        )

        globalVideosRef.setValue(remoteUserVideo)
```

However, the **tags variable** is causing the problem according to the logcat. I've seen other questions that  have the same problem but all of them deal with list of custom Classes in which the actual class is the problem. In my case, I have a list of Strings.

I've checked the class throwing the error but it doesn't make sense

```java
      if (o instanceof List) {
        List<Object> list = (List<Object>) o;
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        for (Object object : list) {
          result.add(serialize(object));
        }
        return result;
      } else {
        throw new DatabaseException(
            "Serializing Collections is not supported, " + "please use Lists instead");
      }
    } else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
      throw new DatabaseException(
          "Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists " + "instead");
    }
```

Actual error:

```
2020-09-28 21:04:51.026 7001-7001/com.andre_max.tiktokclone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.andre_max.tiktokclone, PID: 7001
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:161)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:676)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:168)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
        at com.andre_max.tiktokclone.ui.PostVideoFragment.addVideosToDatabase(PostVideoFragment.kt:226)
        at com.andre_max.tiktokclone.ui.PostVideoFragment.access$addVideosToDatabase(PostVideoFragment.kt:44)
        at com.andre_max.tiktokclone.ui.PostVideoFragment$postVideoInFirebaseStorage$1$1.onSuccess(PostVideoFragment.kt:127)
        at com.andre_max.tiktokclone.ui.PostVideoFragment$postVideoInFirebaseStorage$1$1.onSuccess(PostVideoFragment.kt:44)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I've added breakpoints to both (`addVideosToDatabase(PostVideoFragment.kt:226`) and (`com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:161)`). At both breakpoints, the tags variable is an ArrayList(). I got the actual class and tested it in the kotlin.lang playground.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val remoteVideo = RemoteUserVideo(
        url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...",
        description = "some random text description #rejoicing #random",
        tags = arrayListOf("#rejoicing", "#team"),
        duration = 22403,
        key = "-MINxv7MJi1sLohBMurD",
        dateCreated = 1601367946056,
        likes = 0,
        views = 0,
        creatorUid = "JR1AMpOG1STDJ5pdAW7iZ4mgojo2",
        totalCommentsSize = 0,
        videoThumbnail = null
    )//android.graphics.Bitmap@674d238)
    println(remoteVideo.javaClass.isArray)

//  prints(false)
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from [this code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/d92096257b3e750c72757fc7c4bc9d7393db2046/firebase-database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/core/utilities/encoding/CustomClassMapper.java#L162) in the Firebase Android SDK. As you can see there, the code checks whether the property is a `Collection` before it checks for an array, so it's pretty certain that you're passing an array by the time it gets there.

I recommend putting a breakpoint on the line that is raising the exception (`addVideosToDatabase(PostVideoFragment.kt:226)`), and checking what value that you're passing is or contains an array.

Comment: I've added breakpoints to both (```addVideosToDatabase(PostVideoFragment.kt:226```) and (```com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:161)```) and according to the debugger, the tags variable is an ArrayList<String>.